# Spring Boot H2 data conversion

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, h2

Spring Boot version: `2.1.2.RELEASE`
H2 version: `1.4.197`
Query over JpaRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerStorage extends JpaRepository<Player, Long> {
  List<Player> findByUid(@Param("uid") List<Integer> uid);
}
...
List<Player> foundByUids = playerStorage.findByUid(Arrays.asList(100, 200));
```

Spring generates and executes a query:

```
Data conversion error converting "(100, 200)"; SQL statement:
select
        player0_.id as id1_3_,
        player0_.uid as uid3_3_ 
    from
        player player0_ 
    where
        player0_.uid=(100 , 200)
[22018-197]
...
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "(100, 200)"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at org.h2.value.Value.convertTo(Value.java:1061)
```

H2 says:

```
DATA_CONVERSION_ERROR_1 = 22018
The error with code 22018 is thrown when trying to convert a value to a data type where the conversion is undefined, or when an error occurred trying to convert.
Example:
CALL CAST(DATE '2001-01-01' AS BOOLEAN);
CALL CAST('CHF 99.95' AS INT);
```

I get the same result if I try to execute this query directly from the H2 web console. If I got it right, the problem is in the statement: `player0_.uid=(100 , 200)`. The same query with the **in** `player0_.uid in (100 , 200)` executes fine from the web console.

Also I have the spring boot properties for H2:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, the error is in repository code:

```
public interface PlayerStorage extends JpaRepository<Player, Long> {
  List<Player> findByUid(@Param("uid") List<Integer> uid);
}
```

From [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords) it should be:

```
public interface PlayerStorage extends JpaRepository<Player, Long> {
  List<Player> findByUidIn(@Param("uid") List<Integer> uid);
}
```

Also:

- if "uid" is the field in Player, then @Param is not required
- @Repository is also redundant
- I would suggest to add some validation that list passed to the method is not empty, otherwise it will result in exception.

Answer (score 2):

Try to rename your method to

```
List<Player> findByUidIn(@Param("uids") List<Integer> uids);
```